Why python testing always import the file in another module implicitly
Current I have two files in the same folder, in the source file I import the dlt module
# File: pipeline.py 

import dlt

Another is a test file which import nothing from the source file yet:
import sys
from unittest import mock
sys.modules['dlt'] = mock.MagicMock()


import pytest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


@pytest.fixture
def spark_fixture():
 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Testing PySpark Example").getOrCreate()
 yield spark


def test_sample():
 return True

When I run the test file, I got the error message:
    import dlt
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dlt'
collected 0 items / 1 error

I don’t get it, here is my 2 problems:

I import nothing from the source file, why does python import it for me automatically? I assume this because the error is related to the ‘dlt’ module
Let’s take a step back. Even though I have not installed the module yet, I mock it at the entry of the testing file, why is it not working?


You might in fact be hitting the specific issue discussed in this answer, as you are using pytest it will try to find all modules and hence pipeline.py will be loaded automatically by pytest.
